# Test method to add attribute to session fails

Tags: java, junit, mockito, portlet

Im testing a method that only add a attribute to portletsession with this code:

```
    @Test
    @PrepareForTest({ActionRequest.class, ActionResponse.class, LocalizedLoggerFactory.class})
    public void test_addConfigCookiesFromSession() {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(LocalizedLoggerFactory.class);
        ActionRequest request = PowerMockito.mock(ActionRequest.class);
        PortletSession session = PowerMockito.mock(PortletSession.class);
        when(request.getPortletSession()).thenReturn(session);

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("prueba");
        ConfigPortlet configPortlet = new ConfigPortlet();
        configPortlet.addCookiesToSession(request, list);

        assertNotNull(session.getAttribute("exemptCookiesListSession"));
    }
```

Inside of addcookiestosession i only add a list  like this:

```
PortletSession portletSession = request.getPortletSession();
        portletSession.setAttribute("exemptCookiesListSession", listExemptCookies);
```

But when i do the assert, i have null in `session.getattribute`..what im doing wrong?

Comment: Try getProperty instead of getAttribute and setProperty instead of setAttribut.

Answer (score 0):

Your "session" variable is a mock object.  When you call "setAttribute()" on a mock object, it will do nothing.  Calling "getAttribute()" afterwards will not get the value you sent in the call to "setAttribute()".

It sounds like what you need is something like this (with static imports for mockito):

```
verify(session).setAttribute(eq("exemptCookiesListSession"), anyList());
```